# Select just month and date in datetime.date

Tags: python, datetime

I'm working with the [NYC MVA](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Public-Safety/Motor-Vehicle-Collisions-Crashes/h9gi-nx9) dataset. I've combined the `CRASH DATE` and `CRASH TIME` columns into a single column with format `2017-06-26 22:00:00`. I'd now like to add a categorical column based on [seasons](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/aboutseasons.html). In order to do this, I'm looking to apply a mask to each season name and fill the column based on that, using the following basic structure:

```
df[df['CRASH TIME'].dt.date < dt.date(:,1,2)]
```

The problem is that the `datetime` date Timestamp requires a year input; the dataset spans a number of years. I would like to select *all* years, not any given year. In other words, I'd like to just select the month and date, and not the year. Is there a way to do that using `datetime` Timestamps?

Answer (score 2):

assuming your using pandas for manipulating the data you could do something like this

```
df['day'] = df['CRASH TIME'].apply(lambda r:r.day)
df['month'] = df['CRASH TIME'].apply(lambda r:r.month)
```

Then you can combine them or work with them just as they are.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's a way how to directly compare only a part of `date`, but you can extract the `month` and `day` into a tuple and compare them that way:

```
month_day_left = (df['CRASH TIME'].dt.date.month, df['CRASH TIME'].dt.date.day)
month_day_right = (dt.date.month, dt.date.day)

(2, 1) < (2, 2) # True
(1, 10) < (2, 1) # True
(2, 1) < (1, 30) # False
```

you can eventually wrap this comparison into a custom function and use it that way:

```
df[ is_earlier(df['CRASH TIME'].dt, dt)]
```